# Update statement for multiple set

Tags: sql, sql-update, informix

When I run the update statement below;

```
update acsctrl 
set allowedip = 
('193.200.155.171,86.47.157.113,82.195.133.171,89.101.70.66,93.107.235.216,178.33.192.1,192.168.0.13,82.195.139.244,193.200.155.171,86.47.157.113,82.195.133.171,
89.101.70.66,93.107.235.216,178.33.192.1,192.168.0.13,10.166.68.64,10.166.68.32,10.166.69.55')
where instcode ='GVS'
```

I get the following error:

> 282: Found a quote for which there is no matching quote.

Any advise, quite new to sql

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Just a note to the OP ie @kpakpo , when I look at your last question I have to tell you you need to be more active after the question is asked. People are trying to help you and you give no feedback. Not good.

Comment: I am using informix

Comment: @VBoka apologies do you need more inf from me ?

Answer (score 1):

No need to put braces while updating.

So,This will work for you :

```
update acsctrl 
set allowedip = '193.200.155.171,86.47.157.113,82.195.133.171,89.101.70.66,93.107.235.216,178.33.192.1,192.168.0.13,82.195.139.244,193.200.155.171,86.47.157.113,82.195.133.171,
89.101.70.66,93.107.235.216,178.33.192.1,192.168.0.13,10.166.68.64,10.166.68.32,10.166.69.55'
where instcode ='GVS'
```

Answer (score -1):

execute procedure ifx_allow_newline('t');

update ....;

execute procedure ifx_allow_newline('f');